# Counter of instances for a Class Tree

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Let's say we have a class Tree As following:
`Class Animal`, `Class Dog extends Animal`, `Class Cat extends Animal`.

and we want to count instances for each one of the classes when obviously `countAnimal = countDog + countCat`.

And we want to save as much redundant code as possible. Is there an elegant way to create a counter for all three Classes in `Animal` Class?

Comment: Are you asking for code that can count any one type, or code that can count all types in one pass?

Comment: Both - one for all and two for each one of the childrens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use a static variable for this inside the Animal Class i.e parent of Class Dog and Class Cat.

```
Class Animal {
  private static int countInstance;
  //codes
  public Animal() {
    countInstance++;
  }
  //codes
  public static int getInstanceCount() {
    return countInstance;
  }
}
```

We have used a counter variable `countInstance` to count the number of instances and kept it as a static variable so that values remain the same along with all instances.

```
Class Dog extends Animal{ 
  private static int DogCount;
  public Dog() {
  DogCount++;
  System.out.println("Dog Instance Created");
  }
  public static int getDogCount(){
  return DogCount;
  }
}
Class Cat extends Animal{
  private static int CatCount;
  public Cat() {
  CatCount++;
  System.out.println("Cat Instance Created");
  }
  public static int getCatCount(){
  return CatCount;
  }
}
```

//driver method

```
Dog germanShephard = new Dog();
Cat BengalCat = new Cat();
System.out.println(BengalCat.getInstanceCount()); //Prints 2 
System.out.println(BengalCat.getCatCount() + germanShephard.getDogCount()); 
//Prints countAnimal = countDog + countCat
```

As when you create an object of the Dog, Cat class the parent constructor is called before child constructor and the counter of instances is increased accordingly.

Comment: Note that this counts all instances that have ever been created -- not all extant instances, or instances in a particular collection. Also note that the animal-counting code is broken with the addition of another subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can count all instances of a particular type in a collection with code like this:

```
public static <T extends Animal, U extends T> 
long countAnimalsByClass( Collection<T> animals, Class<U> cls ) {
    return animals.stream().filter( cls::isInstance ).count();
}
```

The generics (`T extends Animal`) allow this one definition to be used on a collection of animals OR on a collection of cats or dogs.

For example with this code:

```
Collection<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    
animals.add( new Cat());
animals.add( new Cat());
    
animals.add( new Dog());
animals.add( new Dog());
animals.add( new Dog());

System.out.println("# cats = " + countAnimalsByClass( animals, Cat.class));
System.out.println("# dogs = " + countAnimalsByClass( animals, Dog.class));
System.out.println("# animals = " + countAnimalsByClass( animals, Animal.class));
```

You get:

```
# cats = 2
# dogs = 3
# animals = 5
```

The function works without modification if someone adds a new subclass:

```
animals.add( new Fish());
System.out.println("# fish = " + countAnimalsByClass( animals, Fish.class));
System.out.println("# animals = " + countAnimalsByClass( animals, Animal.class));
```

Results in:

```
# fish = 1
# animals = 6
```

Comment: Thanks Andy got to knew how we count instances using Collection.